# 20×20 Game of Life in C

Tags: beginner, c, game-of-life

I am new to C, but have experience with Python and R. The following code implements the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and represents my first finger exercise in C. I would like to have some feedback regarding the coding style and conventions in the C community. (I commented out the two Windows specific lines, in case someone wants to run it on another operating system)

```
//gcc -Wextra -Wall -Werror -O3 -march=native -std=c99 -o test.exe gameOfLife.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <Windows.h>

void initField(bool field[],
               const size_t rows,
               const size_t cols,
               const float fill)
{
    // fill everything with zeros
    memset(field, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(bool));

    // fill the desired amount of entries with ones
    srand(time(0));
    for(size_t r = 1; r < rows-1; ++r)
        for(size_t c = 1; c < cols-1; ++c)
            if(rand() / (float)RAND_MAX < fill)
                field[r*rows + c] = 1;
}

unsigned countNeighbors(bool field[], const size_t rows, const size_t entry)
{
    return field[entry-rows-1] + field[entry-rows] + field[entry-rows+1] +
           field[entry-1] +                          field[entry+1] + 
           field[entry+rows-1] + field[entry+rows] + field[entry+rows+1];
}

void updateField(bool field[], const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
{
    // create a new field filled with zeros
    bool tmp[rows * cols];
    memset(tmp, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(bool));

    // apply update rules and set some entries to one
    for(size_t r = 1; r < rows-1; ++r)
        for(size_t c = 1; c < cols-1; ++c) {
            size_t entry = r*rows + c;
            unsigned neighbors = countNeighbors(field, rows, entry);
            // update entry based on neighbors
            if(neighbors == 3 || (neighbors == 2 && field[entry])) 
                tmp[entry] = 1;
        }

    // update the actual field
    memcpy(field, tmp, rows*cols*sizeof(bool));
}

void printField(bool field[], const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
{
    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            printf("%i", field[r*rows + c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    // actual dimensions are (rows-1)*(cols-1), but for convenience
    // we are going to create a border around it filled with zeros
    const size_t rows = 21;
    const size_t cols = 21;
    bool field[rows * cols];

    // initialize the field with ~20% of entries set to 1
    initField(field, rows, cols, 0.2);

    // print and update the field for some iterations
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        printField(field, rows, cols);
        updateField(field, rows, cols);
        //Sleep(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first comment in main() says "actual dimensions are (rows-1)*(cols-1)", but it looks like it's actually "(rows-2)*(cols-2)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good, and surprisingly free of *bona fide* problems, even for code posted here.  I find that I have little or no criticism of its behavior.

C does not have such a strong sense of common stylistic convention as does, say, Java, but here are some things to consider:

- As another answer also points out, using braces around the bodies of loop and conditional constructs is not just a stylistic consideration, but also a strategy for reducing the likelihood of errors being introduced, both during development and during subsequent maintenance.

Failing to use braces where they are not technically required has contributed to real-world bugs of significant consequence.  Using braces may seem a bit unnatural to a person coming from Python, such as yourself, but such a person is especially at risk of writing buggy code if they do not adopt a firm rule of always using braces.  Their eyes are used to attributing significance to indentation that just doesn't apply in C.

By all means, however, *do* indent consistently.  That's not a problem in your code; I just want to underscore that indentation makes code much easier to read, and should not be overlooked.  Indentation was the norm long before Guido van Rossum thought of making it significant.

- Be consistent in how you use spaces.

Your code exhibits some inconsistency about whether binary operators are separated from their operands by spaces, sometimes even within the same expression.  I find code much easier to read when there are spaces around such operators, but if you choose not to place such spaces then at least be consistent about it.

Personally, I prefer also to see space between keywords and parentheses (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.), but not between functions' names and the parentheses around their arguments.  That's a bit easier for me to read and parse, but it is of little significance as long as you're consistent.

- in C, all function arguments are passed *by value*, therefore declaring function parameters to be `const` is of questionable usefulness.

I raise this because you consistently declare function arguments to be `const`, except those that are pointers.  You do not need to do this to avoid the possibility of functions modifying the callers' copies of function arguments.  You also do not need to do it to accept actual arguments that are declared `const`.  The only thing it does for you is to help you enforce a stylistic constraint against functions modifying their own copies of those values (and although some favor such a constraint, I see no particular point to applying it as a universal rule).

Note also that you are a bit inconsistent with this `const`ness, because you do not apply your convention to pointer argument (which is a different consideration from the `const`ness of those pointers' *targets*).

<s>- Make use of initialization.</s>

In C, "initialization" means designating the value that an object will have at its creation, and it is accomplished via (exactly one of) the object's declaration(s).  This is distinct from assigning a value later, even immediately after, and it has its own rules.  For example, when you initialize an aggregate object other than a union, any members not explicitly initialized take default initialization values (generally 0).  Thus this ...

```
bool tmp[rows * cols];
memset(tmp, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(bool));
```

... is both non-idiomatic and unnecessarily expensive.  The idiomatic way would be:

```
bool tmp[rows * cols] = { 0 };
```

That initializes element 0 to 0 (== false) explicitly, and all other elements to 0 implicitly.

Note in particular that that does *not* involve an assignment.  C does not have whole-array assignment, and `{ 0 }` is not an array literal.

- Don't use `printf()` to print string literals

This isn't a big deal, really, but as a matter of style I recommend using `printf()`-family functions only when you're actually relying on them to do some formatting.  For outputting string literals, one of `puts()`, `fputs()`, `putchar()`, `putc()`, or `fputc()` is usually a better choice.  In particular, I would recommend `putchar('\n')` as an improvement on `printf("\n")`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!. About the const: I am still getting into the compiler stuff and I know that all the size_t are passed by value, but I was under the impression that the compiler is able to optimize const values better than non-const values. Is that not correct for the simple built-in types like size_t?

Comment: Also using `bool tmp[rows * cols] = { 0 };` gives the error `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`.

Comment: @JohnDoeJr, the compiler does not need parameters to be declared `const` to know whether you modify them, with the possible exception of the case where you create pointers to them via the address-of operator (`&`).

Comment: @JohnDoeJr, my bad about the initialization, however.  I have stricken that part of my review.

Answer (score 2):

```
//gcc -Wextra -Wall -Werror -O3 -march=native -std=c99 -o test.exe gameOfLife.c
```

This should probably be put into some Makefile (well... the Makefile can be written more idiomatically, but I'm not the person to really ask about Makefiles...)

---

```
srand(time(0));
```

There *may* be better alternatives to this as a random number generator. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931624/667648) seems to suggest that Mersenne Twisters produce higher quality pseudo random numbers *and* that it is faster. However, informally speaking Mersenne Twisters are no longer consider ["high quality enough"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/why-is-the-mersenne-twister-regarded-as-good).

To clarify, I am suggesting the alternative not so much because the output is a "higher quality" random number, but because of speed concerns.

---

This:

```
if(rand() / (float)RAND_MAX < fill)
```

this:

```
for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
```

and this:

```
if(neighbors == 3 || (neighbors == 2 && field[entry]))
```

They all don't use braces. **Please** use braces. To put this in to context, there was a [OpenSSL bug in Mac OSX](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/). **IF** they had used braces, the double `goto fail` would not have mattered<sup>*</sup>. It caused a lot of issues. So I would advise *at the very least* you put the statements on the same line if you don't use brackets.

<sup>* Well, it could have mattered, but autocompletion of brackets in an IDE would mitigate the chances. Better safe than sorry!</sup>